# How to link views (GUI) to the respective controller

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am creating an application in java, following the MVC pattern. 
My program is formed by more interface screens that have to be connected together. Furthermore, the application uses a Derby database. 
My problem is that I can't link views (which contain GUI) to the respective controller. 
Let me explain by indicating more precisely what is contained in the file.

In the package View there are several files that contain all the code to generate a "screen". For example I had the file **Login.java** that is the following:

```
package View;

import Model.*;
import Controller.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Login {

  LoginController loginC;
  RegController regC;

  public JButton accediButton;
  public JButton regButton;
  public JTextField textUsername;
  public JPasswordField textPassword;
  public JLabel labelUsername;
  public JLabel labelPassword;
  public JLabel labelTitolo;
  public JLabel oppureLabel;
  public JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame("Login"); 
  public JPanel panel = new JPanel();

  public Login() {
    panel.setLayout(null);
    setupGUI();
    loginFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  void setupGUI() {

     regButton = new JButton();
     regButton.setLocation(68,206);
     regButton.setSize(80,30);
     regButton.setText("Registrati");
     panel.add(regButton);

     //...other similar code...

     Registrazione regView = new Registrazione();
     loginC = new LoginController(this);
     regC = new RegController(regView);
     accediButton.addActionListener(loginC);
     //regButton.addActionListener(regC);

  }

}
```

The file **Registrazione.java** is very similar and is the following.

```
package View;

import Model.*;
import Controller.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Registrazione {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

  GridBagConstraints c;
  JButton bindietro = new JButton("Indietro");
  JButton bok = new JButton("Ok");
  public JTextField username;
  public JPasswordField password;
  public JTextField nome;
  public JTextField cognome;

  public Registrazione() {
     frame.setTitle("Registrazione"); 
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setVisible(true);

     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

     panel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     panel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     buttonPanel.add(bindietro);
     buttonPanel.add(bok);

     //code...

     frame.pack();
     centerWindow(frame);

     //listener
     login();
     indietro();
  }

  public void login() {
     bok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
           //code...
        }
     });
  }

  public void indietro() {
        bindietro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
              Login log = new Login();
              frame.dispose(); //chiude il frame corrente (Registrazione)
           }
        });
  }

  public static void centerWindow(Window frame) {
     Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
     int x = (int) ((dimension.getWidth() - frame.getWidth()) / 2);
     int y = (int) ((dimension.getHeight() - frame.getHeight()) / 2);
     frame.setLocation(x, y);
  }

}
```

The files that are in the package Controller contain the methods for carrying out checks of data entered by the user. Then perform the query from the database. 
For example, the file **LoginController** is this:

```
package Controller;

import Model.*;
import Model.Studente;
import View.Login.*;
import View.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginController implements ActionListener {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
         String insertedUsername = loginView.textUsername.getText(); 
         String insertedPassword = loginView.textPassword.getText();
         System.out.println(insertedUsername + insertedPassword);
         if(insertedUsername.equals("") || insertedPassword.equals(""))
            System.out.println("Stringhe vuote.");
         boolean res = checkData(insertedUsername, insertedPassword);
         if(res) {
            loginView.loginFrame.dispose(); 
            System.out.println("Dati corretti.");
         }
         else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username o password errati.", "Login error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            loginView.textUsername.setText(insertedUsername); 
            loginView.textPassword.setText(insertedPassword);
            loginView.textUsername.requestFocus();
         }
      }
      catch(SQLException ex) {
         System.err.println("Controller/LoginController - " + ex + ".");
      }
   }

   public boolean checkData(String user, String pass) throws SQLException {
      studente = studente.findByUsername(user);
      boolean bool = false;
      if(studente != null) {
         if(studente.password.equals(pass)) {
            bool = true;
         }
      }
      return bool;
   }

}
```

The file **RegController** is this:

```
package Controller;

import Model.*;
import Model.Studente;
import View.Login.*;
import View.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RegController implements ActionListener {

   public RegController() {

   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      try {
         String insertedUsername = regView.username.getText(); 
         String insertedPassword = regView.password.getText();
         String insertedNome = regView.nome.getText();
         String insertedCognome = regView.cognome.getText();
         System.out.println(insertedUsername + insertedPassword + insertedNome + insertedCognome);
         if(insertedUsername.equals("") || insertedPassword.equals("") || insertedNome.equals("") || insertedCognome.equals(""))
            System.out.println("Stringhe vuote.");

         boolean res = checkData(insertedUsername);
         if(res) { 
            studente.setId("1");
            studente.setUsername(insertedUsername);
            studente.setPassword(insertedPassword);
            studente.setNome(insertedNome);
            studente.setCognome(insertedCognome);
            studente.save();
         }
         else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username già usato, riprova.", "Registrazione error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            regView.username.setText(insertedUsername); 
            regView.password.setText(insertedPassword);
            regView.nome.setText(insertedNome);
            regView.cognome.setText(insertedCognome);            
            regView.username.requestFocus();
         }
      }
      catch(SQLException ex) {
         System.err.println("Controller/LoginController - " + ex + ".");
      }
   }

   public boolean checkData(String user) throws SQLException {
      boolean bool = true;
      studente = studente.findByUsername(user);
      if(studente != null) {
         bool = false;
      }
      return bool;
   }   

}
```

The Model package contains the files that represent objects. For example there's the file **Studente.java** that represents the "student" and that contains methods that perform queries (insert, select, etc.).

What I want to achieve is that, at the launch of the application, was created the first graphical login screen. The controller controls the data inserted by user and compares them with those in the database, and if the data are correct, then the program opens a new page (eg, A.java). 
Instead the user clicks on the button of the sign up, then the app open the page of registration, etc...

I don't know how to do that..

The only idea I came up with is to create an instance of the controller in the view file and pass the data but have not been able to put this idea into practice.. 
Anyway, this idea does not seem very "clean".

Other tips?

Thank you very much and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Please check [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) and [Java Model View Controller (MVC) Design Pattern](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/javamvcdesignpattern.html). Hope it'll help you design more effectively

Comment: @PramodPP Thank you. I read the pages you suggested but it seems a little complicated, there is an easier way?